# "Property 'renderers' does not exist" error during handsontable 7.0.0. upgrade

Tags: handsontable

I'm getting the following error after an upgrade from handsontable 6.2.2 to handsontable 7.0.0

> ERROR in src/app/hot/hot.component.ts(538,26): error TS2339: Property 'renderers' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/allan/git/dcfrontend/node_modules/handsontable/handsontable")'.

The line of code is:

```
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

Is there an easy / obvious fix?

Answer (score 2):

The fix was indeed, easy / obvious.  The following line:

```
import * as Handsontable from "handsontable";
```

Should have been:

```
import Handsontable from "handsontable";
```

(contrary to documentation for angular component)